# Split function not splitting string correctly

Tags: java

I have a string with values separated by a `;`

```
col1;col2;;
```

The last value is empty. I'm getting the number of columns by splitting the string:

```
int columns = myString.split(";").length;
```

However, the above returns 2 instead of 3.

Is this a problem of the split method?

Answer (score 3):

Read the Javadoc :

> This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with the given expression and a limit argument of zero. **Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array**.

You can use `myString.split(";",-1)` to get an array with trailing empty strings.